# Mysql Slow Insert

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, insert

I have the following InnoDB table:

```
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| doc_id    | char(32)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| staff     | char(18)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| timestamp | timestamp | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

With these keys:

```
+--------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| staff_online |          0 | PRIMARY         |            1 | id          | A         |      277350 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| staff_online |          1 | timestamp       |            1 | timestamp   | A         |      277350 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| staff_online |          1 | staff_timestamp |            1 | timestamp   | A         |      277350 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| staff_online |          1 | staff_timestamp |            2 | staff       | A         |      277350 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+--------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

I just noticed that `in mysql-slow.log` I sometimes have an INSERT query on this table which takes more than 1 second

```
INSERT INTO `staff_online` (`doc_id`, `staff`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('150b60a0ab8c5888bdbbb80bd8b7f8a2', 'asia', '2011-01-29 16:52:54')
```

I'm really puzzled why it takes so long. How can I speed it up?

BTW: Each day there're ~80 slow INSERTS and 40 slow UPDATES like this.

Comment: How many rows are in the table, and are you sure all inserts are slow?

Comment: There are 277259 rows and only some inserts are slow (rare).

Comment: You seem to have two indexes, one by `timestamp` an another by `timestamp, staff`. The latter is sufficient to search by `timestamp`, you can drop the former.

Comment: Nice thanks. But this isn't AFAIK the cause, of the slow insert query?

Comment: make you are not running any complex join via cronjob

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes it is not the query itself which causes a slowdown - another query operating on the table can easily cause inserts to slow down due to transactional isolation and locking. Your slow queries might simply have been waiting for another transaction(s) to complete. This is fairly common on a busy table, or if your server is executing long/complex transactions.

Another significant factor will be the overall performance of your database: how your `my.cnf` file is tuned, how the server itself is tuned, what else the server has running on it, and of course, what hardware the server is running.

The linux tool `mytop` and the query `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` can be helpful to see possible trouble spots. General linux performance tools can also show how busy your disks are, etc.

Given the nature of this table, have you considered an alternative way to keep track of who is online? In MySQL, I have used a `MEMORY` table for such purposes in the past. A NoSQL data store might also be good for this type of information. Redis could store this as a sorted set with much success (score == timestamp).

Further reading:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-tuning.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-storage-engine.html
- http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set

Comment: I added the following to my mysql config it should gain me some more performance. We will see.
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
    innodb_support_xa=0
    innodb_buffer_pool_size=536870912

Comment: Btw i can't use the memory engine, because i need to have the online data in some persistent way, for later analysis.

Comment: @Kalkin: That sounds like an excuse to me - "business requirements demand it." Sometimes overly broad business requirements need to be re-evaluated in the face of technical hurdles. I'd advising re-thinking your requirements based on what you actually need to know. But overall, my post is about: don't just look at this one query, look at everything your database is doing. We don't know what that is, so we can only help so much.

Comment: Thanks for your hint with innodb optimizations. Since i enabled them, i had no slow inserts any more.

Answer (score 13):

> There are 277259 rows and only some inserts are slow (rare)

Whenever a B-Tree page is full, it needs to be split which takes some time.  Insert performance is also slower the more indexes you have, since each insert updates all indexes. `9000` has already stated correctly that your (timestamp,staff) index covers the (timestamp) index in 95% of cases, there are very rare cases when a single-column (timestamp) index will be required for better performance.

There are also some periodic background tasks that can occasionally slow down an insert or two over the course of a day.

Additionally, another reason for delays is simply database activity.  If you have transactions that are locking pages that the insert needs to update (or page-split), the insert has to wait until the write locks are acquiesced.  These other activity do not even need to actually start a transaction, and they don't even have to be read-read contention; you can also have write-write contention or a queue built up from heavy activity.

And the last possible reason - your database server is out of resources, be it memory or CPU or network i/o.  There is only so much a server can do, so it will have to wait until it has enough resources.

Comment: @kalkin - it is one factor as noted above, but not the *only* one. Removing it alone will *not* make the slow inserts vanish, but it is certainly a good idea. Storage engines like InnoDB have background tasks that can periodically slow an insert or two. Other factors like automated backups (MySQL), full-image snapshots (server backup), page splitting etc can also cause rare delays.

Comment: The most insert delays are when there is lot's of traffic in our "rush hour" on the page.

Comment: @kalkin - I updated the answer with 2 more possible reasons given your rush hour scenario.

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK it isn't out of ressources. Perhaps it just simple db activity, and i have to rethink the way i store the online status. I will monitor this evening the database, and will have more to report.

Comment: The Database works now flawless i have no INSERT problems anymore

Comment: @kalkin can you kindly tell us what you did to overcome the slow query INSERTs?

Answer (score 5):

If you're inserting into a table in large dense bursts, it may need to take some time for housekeeping, e.g. to allocate more space for the table and indexes.

If don't want your app to wait, try using [`INSERT DELAYED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-delayed.html) though it does have its downsides.

Comment: INSERT DELAYED seems to be a nice solution for the problem, but it doesn't work on InnoDB :(

Comment: It is also deprecated in 5.6.6 and removed in 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in a cluster enviroment, auto-increment columns may slow inserts.  Try tweaking  ndb_autoincrement_prefetch_sz (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-system-variables.html#sysvar_ndb_autoincrement_prefetch_sz)

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be back-level on your MySQL installation, we noticed a lot of that sort of slowness when using version 4.1.

Answer (score -3):

As my experience InnoDB performance is lower than MyISAM.
Have you try using MyISAM instead?
Or maybe you need to tweak your InnoDB configuration:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-configuration.html
Hope that help.