# A Most Puzzling MySQL Problem: Queries Sporadically Slow

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

This is the most puzzling MySQL problem that I've encountered in my career as an administrator.  Can anyone with MySQL mastery help me a bit on this?:

Right now, I run an application that queries my MySQL/InnoDB tables many times a second.  These queries are simple and optimized -- either single row inserts or selects with an index.

Usually, the queries are super fast, running under 10 ms.  However, once every hour or so, all the queries slow down.  For example, at 5:04:39 today, a bunch of simple queries all took more than 1-3 seconds to run, as shown in my slow query log.

Why is this the case, and what do you think the solution is?

I have some ideas of my own: maybe the hard drive is busy during that time?  I do run a cloud server (rackspace) But I have flush_log_at_trx_commit set to 0 and tons of buffer memory (10x the table size on disk).  So the inserts and selects should be done from memory right?

Has anyone else experience something like this before?  I've searched all over this forum and others, and it really seems like no other MySQL problem I've seen before.

Comment: You should ask this on http://serverfault.com/. Do you have other sites on the same box? Any cron jobs running? Do you have enough physical memory to keep it from swapping?

Comment: There's only that one site, but there very well could be background activity going on.  Is there a way to set innoDB so that it writes to memory as a buffer, and only maintains persistence in the HDD?

I definitely have more than enough memory: the tables are < 1GB total and I have 8GB of memory.

Comment: [galz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/610995/galz) commented (way back) that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837903/mysql-slow-insert) could help you

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for sudden stalls.  For example - even if you are using flush_log_at_trx_commit=0, InnoDB will need to pause briefly as it extends the size of data files.

My experience with the smaller instance types on Rackspace is that IO is completely awful.  I've seen random writes (which should take 10ms) take 500ms.

There is nothing in built-in MySQL that will help you identify the problem easier.  What you might want to do is take a look at Percona Server's slow query log enhancements.  There's a specific feature called "profiling_server" which can break down time:
http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-server:features:slow_extended#changes_to_the_log_format